# I do not see a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the course of development of JS, faced with such a situation. My code:

```
Object.prototype.show = function () {
 $('span[data-search]').on('click', function (evt) {
     var data_search = $(this).data('search');

     $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
          $(this).find('button.synConfirm').on('click', function(){
              console.log(data_search);    // Not see variable
          });
     });
 }):
});
```

Ie if you click on the span opens a modal window (Bootstrap 3). Then when you click on the button in the modal window, I should have access to the variable data-search announced in the beginning of the method, but I do not have access to it ...

**Question: Why? After I identified her to call console.log (), .. How do I get it?**

Comment: Is the data-search of span initialized by the modal window? I think data_search will not update if the attribute changes.

Comment: No, in modal window data-search not initialized. I need to send data-search value to modal window. And my question, why I'm not see this value, because as I understand, I do all correct...?

Comment: The code looks correct, what you exactly get in the console? Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Redefined the context variable, and it worked.
var data_search;
Object.prototype.show = function () {

Comment: @JuliaKIngston If you have solved the problem(As I can see from the above comment) then paste it in the answer section so that it will be helpful for the future users

Comment: Whyever are you extending `Object.prototype`, when you don't ever use the object on which the function `show` was called? What are you tring to accomplish?